# Clearing a Binary I/O Buffer

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, reportlab

I have this function generatePlots() that returns two binary I/O buffers and then the read by another function to display the plots. This function is invoked when I click a button.

My issue that I am currently having is, when I click the button several times to generate the plots it appears that buffers does not update with new data it however keep garbage data  or data from the previous event as result displaying not was expected.

My question what is the proper to flush the buffer every time the button is clicked?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from reportlab.platypus import Image
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        button = QPushButton('Generate', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100,70)
        button.clicked.connect(self.generate_report)

        self.show()

    def generatePlots(data):

        # Plot 1
        plt.plot(data.time * 1e6, data.signal_volts)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
        buf = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buf, format="png")
        # buf.truncate(0)
        buf.seek(0)

        # Plot 2
        y1 = [-12, 0]
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(data.frequencies * 1e-6, data.dB[0:int(data.dB.size/2 + 1)])
        plt.axis([0,data.frequency * 1e-6 * 2,-12,0.1])
        plt.grid(True)

        buf_2 = BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(buf_2, format="png")
        # buf_2.truncate(0)
        buf_2.seek(0)

        return (buf, buf_2)

    def generate_report(self):
            test= Scan()
            test_plot, test2_plot = self.generatePlots(test)
            story = []
            test1 = Image(test_plot, 4*inch, 3*inch)
            test2 = Image(test2_plot , 4*inch, 3*inch)
            story.append(test1)
            story.append(test2)
            document.build(story)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited the code

Comment: That is not an MRE, If it were an MRE then it should make a copy-paste of your code and be able to execute your problem but clearly it is not.

Comment: @eyllanesc updated. This as simple as I can make it. As it is apart of a way larger program.

Comment: It cannot execute your code since "Scan" is not defined